Email delivery failure
The response was:
DNS Error: DNS type 'mx' lookup of comle.terre.defense.fr responded with code NOERROR DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of localhost. responded with code NXDOMAIN DNS type 'a' lookup of localhost. responded with code NXDOMAIN

When i send email by my phone, i just got like this email is not delivered ‘failure’

> nslookup -type=mx comle.terre.defense.fr

Non-authoritative answer:
comle.terre.defense.fr  MX preference = 0, mail exchanger = localhost

The domain has not made their mail server visible publicly.

Better to say, this domain made their mail server publicly unavailable. They specifically telling that they aren't willing to receive any (external) mail for this domain.
